# Checkbox styling doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, checkbox

I'm making a form where accordians hide a multiply checkbox, and so far so good!

Then, the styling where I use the label to make my own style of checkmarks. It works fine!

However, when it comes to Internet Explorer, it just doesn't work :( Why?

---

#### Note:

It's not me who wrote all the code, I've just have to make the checkbox work, and leave the rest as it is.

---

---

#### Edit:

I can't seem to find the right solution, so maybe I have to have a completely different design for Internet Explorer to work?

---

#### My code:

```css
.specialCheck2 font {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Verdana";
}

.specialCheck2 {
    position: relative;
}

.specialCheck2 label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    top: 2px;
    left: 0;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #757575;
    font-size: 79%;
}

.specialCheck2 label:after {
    opacity: 0;
    content: 'x';
    position: absolute;
    color: #00035a;
    background: #00035a;
    width: 75%;
    height: 75%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1;
    line-height: 10px;
    margin: 14%;
}

.specialCheck2 label:hover::after {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.specialCheck2 input[type=checkbox]:checked + label::after {
    opacity: 1;
}

.specialCheck2 input[type=checkbox] {
        margin: 0 5px 0 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="specialCheck2">
     <font>
         <input type="checkbox" name="Tilmelding" id="newsletterCheckbox2">JA TAK! Send mig kursuskatalog og kalender
         <label for="newsletterCheckbox2"></label>
     </font>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version of IE do you need it to work in? Also place your code into a jsfiddle or something similar so we can play around with it.

Comment: As meny as posible. But 9-11 is okey :) There is a snippet now.

Comment: The solution im going with is i make an IE only stylesheet, at remove the labels. So no styling to IE

Answer (score 0):

This answer won't tell you how to fix your code for Internet Explorer, but this will explain why.

All modern web browsers, Firefox and Chrome for example, use something called [WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit). WebKit is a pre-built rendering engine created by Apple, Adobe and KDE. And you've probably guessed, Internet Explorer doesn't use this; Microsoft is stubborn and use its own. When writing CSS that affects all web browsers, you are going to have to take things like this into consideration, and re-write some CSS for different browsers.

The reason it will work in [Internet Explorer 9](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_9) and [Internet Explorer 10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_11#Internet_Explorer_10) is because they probably took some components out of WebKit or saw the common CSS commands WebKit was making and decided to 'adopt' these commands and put them into their browser.

Hopefully with the release of [Edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge), Internet Explorer will die out and issues like this won't occur any more. But in the meantime MSDN (Microsoft Development Network) has a page dedicated to CSS compatibility in Internet Explorer, *[CSS Compatibility in Internet Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508(v=vs.85).aspx)*.

I hope this answers your question on why it wasn't working in earlier versions of Internet Explorer and their outdated web browsers. I even saw someone asking about CSS in [Netscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netscape_%28web_browser%29) :/ .

EDIT:
And your `::after` command does not work in [Internet Explorer 8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8) and before.

[image]

[Source](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_after.asp)

Comment: Yeah i know thay use webkit and explore dont. and on the page u linked to it says that the Combinaton css ive used should be supported :(

Comment: have you declared a ```<!DOCTYPE>``` [more info](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp) ?

Comment: Yeah its declared. Why is there always problems with IE :(

Comment: because it's outdated since IE6. I'm sorry i couldn't be much help!

Comment: I hate IE. Always making truble!